# How to minimize this query

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

My query takes too long to execute and page is going on 504 error for that, how can I fix this problem with this query?

```
SELECT *,
                    schedules.id AS ids
                FROM 
                    schedules 
                INNER JOIN
                (
                    SELECT saxeli,gvari, id, pn
                    FROM dacva
                )
                    dacva 
                        ON schedules.person_id=dacva.id 
                INNER JOIN
                (
                    SELECT dasaxeleba,kodi, id, active
                    FROM obieqti
                    WHERE active=1
                )
                    obieqti 
                        ON schedules.object_id=obieqti.id 
                    INNER JOIN
                (
                    SELECT category, xelfasi, zeganakveturi, premia, object_id, date_ended
                    FROM object_guard WHERE date_ended<'$date_start'
                )
                    object_guard 
                        ON schedules.object_id=object_guard.object_id AND schedules.category=object_guard.category
```

Comment: Hi Ted, I'm doubting that a single plain query would not help much. Please provide the table schemas and your intention, what is your expected outcome

Comment: Remove all subqueries, build plain query. Then check the tables for suitable indices.

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

What MySQL version, does it support 'WITH clause' (Common table expressions)?

Start by removing '*' from the very top, the less cols the better chance it will be better optimized.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't provide a schema or an EXPLAIN, I'm guessing that the problem comes from the subqueries - you may be confusing the query optimizer.

So, remove the subqueries (you may need to replace * with the specific columns you want to retrieve):

```
SELECT *,
       schedules.id AS ids
FROM   schedules
       INNER JOIN dacva
               ON schedules.person_id = dacva.id
       INNER JOIN obieqti
               ON schedules.object_id = obieqti.id
                  AND obieqti.active = 1
       INNER JOIN object_guard
               ON schedules.object_id = object_guard.object_id
                  AND schedules.category = object_guard.category
                  AND object_guard.date_ended < '$date_start'
```

Next, you need to make sure there are indexes on the columns in the joins and where clause. I would especially make sure `object_guard.date_ended` has an index.